# Page numbers of multi-page tables in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long table that breaks over a page, and I have placed a caption at the bottom of the table. I wish to refer to the page number on which this table starts (for a "list of tables" listing), but it refers to the page on which the caption sits (and the table ends).

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Or if anyone could suggest a better SE site on which to post this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this, if you're willing to add a TC field above your table (and hope no-one deletes it, as many users aren't familiar with these nowadays).

1. Above your table, insert a TC field with some placeholder text eg "ABC", and select the options "TC entry in doc with multiple tables" and "Outline level" set to 1.
2. Select the placeholder text in the TC field, and insert your caption in the usual way (retaining the quote marks).
3. Select the caption (ie the text within the quotes) and create a bookmark (eg name it as bkTbl2 if it's Table 2 in your doc).
4. Below the table, you'll just insert a cross-reference (not a caption) - and the cross-reference will be to the bookmark text for bkTbl2 (so in the Cross-reference dialog, select "Bookmark" for Reference type, and "Bookmark text" for Insert reference to.
5. Once your cross-reference is inserted, format it with the Caption style (so it looks like the rest of your captions.
6. Modify your table of figures field for your tables, to add the switch \f, so that it picks up the TC fields(s).

   { TOC \f \h \z \c "Table" }